# react three fiber nested click issue

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

In cases where two objects stand one after the other (in fact, when two objects intersect), when I click on the front object, I unintentionally click on the back object as well. you can check the example. I just wanted to click on the front object.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vy7D.png)

https://codesandbox.io/s/interaction-forked-3ftkfu

Comment: onPointerDown={(e) => {
  e.stopPropagation()

}}
solved my problem. :)